# Finding MAMP default web page

Tags: mamp

Installed MAMP. Cannot figure out how to get to the default web page to add some content to it. Using terminal what steps would I need to take to locate the page? I also cannot find the MAMP directory (if any).

Comment: in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/

Answer (score 0):

based on this page your document root is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`

Reference: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp/

I have 0 experience with Mac OS, however; I know some Linux.

> Using terminal what steps would I need to take to locate the page?

**Option 1:**

```
`php -i | grep 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'`
```

**Option 2:**

1. Create a file:

   `echo '<?php infophp();?>' > info.php`
2. execute it:

   `php info.php | grep 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'`

**Option 3:**

```
 `sudo apachectl -S | grep 'DocumentRoot'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see how to respond to a comment. Anyway I created a file called index.php in that directory. Maybe there's some other filenames I could use too. But this is a start.

Comment: you can't comment yet, because you don't have enough privileges (I think you need 10 points). Please, do not create an answer like this for respond, you can always edit your question, until you have enough privileges. If you think my answer helps you with your question, I will really appreciate if you can accept the answer. Thank you so much!